# Pandas: get first 10 elements of a series

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

I have a data frame with a column `tfidf_sorted` as follows:

```
   tfidf_sorted

0  [(morrell, 45.9736796), (football, 25.58352014...
1  [(melatonin, 48.0010051405), (lewy, 27.5842077...
2  [(blues, 36.5746634797), (harpdog, 20.58669641...
3  [(lem, 35.1570832476), (rottensteiner, 30.8800...
4  [(genka, 51.4667410433), (legendaarne, 30.8800...
```

The `type(df.tfidf_sorted)` returns `pandas.core.series.Series`.

This column was created as follows:

```
df['tfidf_sorted'] = df['tfidf'].apply(lambda y: sorted(y.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

where `tfidf` is a dictionary.

How do I get the first 10 key-value pairs from `tfidf_sorted`?

Comment: That's a very unidiomatic way of using pandas. Why store lists in a Series? Why not use columns in a DataFrame?

Comment: Sure, I thought so too. Could you please suggest an alternate method?

Comment: Each of those columns (i.e. the first is 'morrell', 'melatonin', etc) in an actual column in a DataFrame?

Comment: No, there is one column `tfidf_sorted` and it's first row is `[(morrell, 45.9736796), (football, 25.58352014...`

Comment: Right, and I'm saying that's a really awkward way of doing it. Instead, why not have that as four columns?

Comment: Not sure I can. This column is created from another column `tfidf`, where each of it's row is a `dictionary`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
from itertools import chain 

#flat nested lists
a = list(chain.from_iterable(df['tfidf_sorted']))
#sorting
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
#get 10 top
print (a[:10])
```

Or if need top 10 per row add `[:10]`:

```
df['tfidf_sorted'] = df['tfidf'].apply(lambda y: (sorted(y.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))[:10])
```

Comment: Thanks!. The second answer worked. For the first one, do I need to import a library?

Comment: Yes, I add it to answer. But first answer return top 10 of all values in all rows.

Comment: Thanks. Second answer is what I was looking for.