# How to get field which has fifth in the order of the highest value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and I have dataset something like this:

```
**ID name total-cost**
  1  a    7
  2  b    4
  3  c    1
  4  e    6
  5  f    80
  6  k    85
```

So I need to get the fifth value in the order of the highest of total-cost, which is here 4 [85 80 7 6 **4** 1]. Not name, not ID, just a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort and then use `iloc` to get the fifth value:

```
df.sort_values('total-cost', ascending=False)['total-cost'].iloc[4]
```

Or use `nlargest(5)` to get the 5 largest , and then use `iloc` to get the last value from that:

```
df['total-cost'].nlargest(5).iloc[-1]
```

Comment: [Series.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) returns them in sorted order according to the documents.

Comment: Thanks ALollz, I skimmed over that part. So it *should* work

Comment: You could also use `pd.Series.rank` for some finer control.

Comment: And If I want to get the array of first 5 values, like this: [85 80 7 6 4], how I can do it? I tried with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867061/pandas-get-first-10-elements-of-a-series, but that didn't help me. Sorry If I am boring, I am new in pandas. :/

Comment: `df['total-cost'].nlargest(5).values`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `nlargest(n)` in order to get the n largest numbers as below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',7],['b',4],['c',1],['e',6],['f',80],['k',85]], columns=['name','total_cost'])
In [2]: df.total_cost.nlargest(5)
Out[2]: 
5    85
4    80
0     7
3     6
1     4
Name: total_cost, dtype: int64
```

`df.nlargest(n)` returns a pandas Series with the original index and the n largest values

If all you need is the 5th largest value, you can use `df.total_cost.nlargest(5).reset_index().total_cost[4]`